# Netsuite Inventory Item Custom Fields Update

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to figure out how to update a custom field on InventoryItem record in Netsuite.  I can update regular fields, but can not seem to update anything

```
InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem();
WriteResponse response;
List<CustomFieldRef> oCustomFieldRefList = new List<CustomFieldRef>();

item.internalId = "9";
StringCustomFieldRef objStringCustomFieldRef = new StringCustomFieldRef();
objStringCustomFieldRef.internalId = "custitem_main_photo";
objStringCustomFieldRef.value = "http://www.google.com/test.jpg";
oCustomFieldRefList.Add(objStringCustomFieldRef); 

item.customFieldList = oCustomFieldRefList.ToArray();
response = _nsService.update(item);
```

The status returned by the update call is Success.  It just doesn't update the custom field.  I've tried different fields and types, but nothing seems to save.

Comment: Does the field show in your SOAP request in Web Services Log? If not NetSuite is thinking the value is null.

Answer (score 1):

The internalId of the custom field is the numeric id, not the string id.  Not sure why the documentation all shows the string id value, but using the number fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Hi @Brian is there any specific permission that NetSuite has to have in order to  update the custom Field List?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning internal Id, assign scriptId.

Turn this

```
objStringCustomFieldRef.internalId = "custitem_main_photo";
```

to this:

```
objStringCustomFieldRef.scriptId = "custitem_main_photo";
```